# Map size different from expected value after adding values to the map

Tags: c++, dictionary

Basically I have a edgeCostMap of type

```
map<pair<int, float>, int>
```

and a vector of 42 vertices. I loop through the vector of vertices and add values to the map as follows:

```
for(int vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < V.size(); vertexIndex++)
{
    pair<int, float> toAdd;
    toAdd.first = vertexIndex;
    toAdd.second = V[vertexIndex].edgeCollapseCost;
    edgeCostMap[toAdd] = vertexIndex;
}
```

However after the loop has been finished and I print out the map contents as follows:

```
for(map<pair<int, float> ,int>::iterator it = edgeCostMap.begin(); it != edgeCostMap.end(); it++) 
{
    logFile<<"Vertex "<<it->second<<" has cost "<<it->first.second<<" has "<<mapVF[it->second].size()<<"neighbors"<<endl;
}
```

I only get back 12 statements. Is my mapping done incorrectly?

Compare function:

```
class comparator {
public:
    bool operator()(const std::pair<int, float>& a, const std::pair<int, float>& b) const {
        return a.second < b.second;
    }
};
```

Comment: map keys can not be duplicated，maybe std::multimap is your needed.http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/

Comment: From what I understand my key is currently a pair <int, float> where the first element in the pair will reference the distinct vertex. Where is the duplication?
I need a data structure that can keep a bunch of pair<int, float> that can maintain the list of pairs sorted according to the float value. I'm not sure if multimap is suitable for that.

Comment: std::pairs are sorted by default by the first element and then by the second, so to make your map sort the way you want it to, you must provide a custom compare functor when defining it. Also, from the code you provided, Ron Tang's answer looks like the most probable cause, so when adding element to the map check that the keys (pairs) are indeed unique.

Comment: Hi,jing,you can print all your keys, look at these keys.

Comment: @lonut I did implement a comparator for this map. I'm still confused as to where the duplication in the key is.

Comment: @Ron Tang I printed out my keys and got only 12 back.

Comment: If you don't post the relevant code all you're going to get is speculation. You have a bug in some code you haven't shown. Maybe you have duplicates. Maybe your comparator is broken. Or something else.

Comment: @jing Print the toAdd pairs when inserting in the map.

Comment: @jing, Are you sure there are no duplicate of 42 keys, give us your compare function and your keys.

Comment: Also note that if you provide a compare function, that function is also used on insertions to determine if two keys are equivalent: two keys are considered equivalent if the compare function returns false reflexively (returns false both when called with (key1, key2) and when called with (key2, key1). So if your compare function just compares the floats from the pairs, the vertexIndex that you say is different for every pair has no effect on key uniqueness. So a key will be a duplicate or not based only on the float value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparator considers two keys equal (neither less than the other) if their floats are equal. You cannot put two equal keys in a map. You probably want to use the default comparator but put the `float` first in the set. This will sort first on the float and second on the integer, ensuring the keys are not equal if their integers differ.